How to scroll normally (without snap) on a specific section in FullPage.js?
I am trying to build a website where I can use scroll snap for the first two sections and then scroll normally through a long section (300vh).
How can I accomplish this effect? I haven't found any place that explains it properly, so help is much needed.
I have tried using scrollOverflow: true; as mentioned in the FullPage.js documentation but it's not scrolling properly. It either gets stuck on the long section or doesn't scroll at all inside this section.
EDIT: Found the answer! There is a CSS file link that includes styles for fullpage.js, and after including it, everything will work fine. Here is the CodePen.
https://codepen.io/cftyftyj/pen/ExqjJee
here is the css link:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullpage.js@4.0.29/dist/fullpage.min.css

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  You said that you've made an attempt with scrollOverview already.  Could you show us that code?

https://codepen.io/cftyftyj/pen/vYoOdPJ

I meant, could you edit your post and type out the code?

No problem. I didn't place it before because I felt it was an easy solution, and debugging a messy code would be harder to accomplish. But it's good to include it just in case, you're right

Haven’t I already done it mate?  it apears in the question on my side

I edited to create a snippet but it perhaps does not clearly reproduce the issue as it stands currently - or at least not super obvious here

The code is’nt scrolling in the way I described I don’t get what you are saying

i didnt want to include the code because i have no idea how to make the thing i am looking for and there is no information elsewhere. If u know how to make the code i am looking for and share a direction it would be much appreciated

You are missing the fullpage.css file.
Make sure to include it on the head of your page.
Read more on the fullpage.js docs:
https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/docs/#including-files
You can find a full example on the fullPage.js example page:
https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html
See the source code.
